# Setting up linux based small office network

Tags: linux, domain, controller

I like to setup a Server and Workstation sort of network in linux (like we have Domain Controller in windows) where all the desktops login where authenicated with server, how this can be done.

I prefer CENTOS 5.4 for server and FEDORA 12 for dektop

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

If you mean an active directory domain controller, there [are](http://grok.lsu.edu/Article.aspx?articleId=6135) [articles](http://www.linux.com/archive/feed/40983) describing how to authenticate using LDAP and extensions to the AD servers. The answer may be more involved that can be easily summed up here, so you might want to google for "fedora authenticate active directory" and find a tutorial on the webbertubes. Make sure you have decent backups ahead of time before modifying your servers.

Methods can vary depending on winbind, LDAP, Samba...you might have to sift through articles (and pay attention to dates, since you probably want what's most recent) to find a method that works in your situation.

Answer (score 1):

There is a product called [SME Server](http://wiki.contribs.org/Main_Page) which appears to be CentOS preconfigured for use as a small office server.

It provides file and print sharing, email, internet connections, firewall, remote access, directory services, web hosting, backups and automatic updates. It is CentOS after all so you can install other software if you need to.

This should provide a good solution and I think meets your requirements and there is a community around it for further support and ideas.

It is also free to download.

Comment: Just been looking at the site some more and there are repositories there for preconfigured packages such as smeserver-spamassassin. There is a contribs repo too.

Comment: +1 SME is particularly easy for non-admins to look after.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you set up an LDAP server such as OpenLDAP and then tell boxes to authenticate against it. Alternatives are Kerberos and Samba.

Comment: OpenLDAP is a directory service.  Kerberos provides authentication services. Samba is a set of utilities that reimplement the CIFS protocol on *nix.  All three are complimentary components that do different things; they are not alternatives.

Comment: I mean, setting up a) OpenLDAP and using pam_ldap, b) Kerberos with its own database and c) Samba as a PDC with tdbsam and Winbind.